# LyX multiple bibliographies: Illegal, another \bibdata command

Tags: bibtex, lyx

Wanting to set up a dissertation with LyX, I tried to configure it for my university's format that requires both a *Bibliography* and a *List of References* as separate parts, using LyX 2.2.0 under Windows 10.

LyX 2.x supposedly allows this, and is documented in **3.1.3 Multiple Bibliographies** of the **Additional L<sub>Y</sub>X Features**. I followed the advice to the letter, yet I get an annoying BibTeX error `Illegal, another \bibdata command`. The PDF *looks* OK, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a long time to find the answer, but [this is what worked](http://lyx-users.lyx.narkive.com/RdEZMhBw/document-doews-not-compile-with-rc1-and-multiple-bibliograpies#post19).

> You have to close and open the LyX document.

Sounds like an annoying bug in LyX with temporary files? Anyway, it's the solution that worked.

Comment: Thank you for writing this answer up! This was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not per se LyX-specific. See [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33575).

Comment: Welcome to TSE. How does that answer the question?

Comment: "You've once again done a BibTeX run for the main file. Don't do it! chapterbib does not support BiBTeX runs for the main file only for the included files." One arrives here, if searching for \bibdata. The thread above in external forum discussing this issue from another perspective.